# Cannot create BOOL from object of class NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am seeing this error when I load a window from a NIB. The error appears deep in Apple code. My loading code all executes correctly and when it is running all the outlets are set up correctly.

```
Cannot create BOOL from object <NSWindow: 0x7f883b44f770> of class NSWindow
```

Here is the code thats being called

```
- (void)awakeFromNib{    
    [self showLoginSheet];
}

- (void)showLoginSheet
// User has asked to see the custom display. Display it.
{
    if (!self.loginSheet)
        [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"LoginSheet" owner:self];
        //Check the myCustomSheet instance variable to make sure the custom sheet does not already exist

    [NSApp beginSheet: self.loginSheet
       modalForWindow: [[NSApp delegate] window]
        modalDelegate: self
       didEndSelector: NULL
          contextInfo: NULL];
}
```

And the stacktrace is

```
2012-07-21 21:09:57.575 MingleLookBooks[15934:503] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot create BOOL from object <NSWindow: 0x7f883b44f770> of class NSWindow'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91305f56 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff874b9d5e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91305d8a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   AppKit                              0x00007fff9038a394 _NSBoolFromValue + 421
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff903b1c5a -[NSEditableBinder hiddenState] + 83
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff903b1bdf -[NSEditableBinder _hiddenStateWithMode:] + 41
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff90389eaa -[NSEditableBinder _setStatesImmediatelyInObject:mode:triggerRedisplay:] + 579
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff90389c60 -[NSEditableBinder _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:context:] + 123
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff901a1643 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueBindingCreation) bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:] + 591
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff9019a959 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 1079
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff90190f73 loadNib + 322
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff90190470 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 217
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff9019038b +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibFile:externalNameTable:withZone:] + 141
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff901902ce +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 364
    14  MingleLookBooks                     0x000000010ef0917a -[AppController showLoginSheet] + 138
    15  MingleLookBooks                     0x000000010ef08ffb -[AppController awakeFromNib] + 43
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff912fcfb1 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 49
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff912fcf32 -[NSSet makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 274
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff9019a9ff -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 1245
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff90190f73 loadNib + 322
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff90190470 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 217
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff9019038b +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibFile:externalNameTable:withZone:] + 141
    22  AppKit                              0x00007fff901902ce +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 364
    23  AppKit                              0x00007fff9040106f NSApplicationMain + 398
    24  MingleLookBooks                     0x000000010ef08f32 main + 34
    25  MingleLookBooks                     0x000000010ef08f04 start + 52
)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

As you can see from the stack trace, this seems to be nothing to do with my code. What am I doing wrong? I have no clue and the other answers to similar questions are not really helping.

Comment: It looks like one of your bindings is set up incorrectly in your XIB.

Comment: Its in a AppController Class, With the nib file's owner as AppController

Comment: @Wevah you were right, The Window was pointing at the view instead of the window!

Comment: (I guess I'll undelete my answer, then… ;) )

Comment: I'd like this question reopening. Wevah's answer just saved me a long debugging session - I got to this question from Google searching for the error text and the answer fixed my issue immediately. I've reworded the question to make it less specific (although it was pretty good already).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like one of your bindings is set up incorrectly in your XIB.

Comment: This topic helped me also, almost exactly matching my problem, and it clarified where I needed to place my attention. So, anyway, not too "localized", and worthy of being open.